# File Path Characters

Tags: xna, .net, character, file

I have a simple question that I can't find a answer to:

With the .NET Framework what is the difference in saying `"folder1/folder2/file"` and `"folder1\\folder2\\file"` in a file directory? Is there even a difference?

Also what does the "@" character do? I'm not sure if this is XNA specific or .NET specific but here is an example: `ContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(@"SpriteSheets/Tile");`

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIk, `@"S:\ome\path\file.ext"` will turn the string into `"S:\\ome\\path\\file.ext"` for you, so you don't have to escape it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a resource on what `@""`-style string literals are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=vs.71).aspx).

Basically they turn off escaping. So, for example, you only need `@"\"`, instead of `"\\"` to get the `\` character.

Another example: `@"\t"` gives you `\t`, whereas `"\t"` (no at symbol) gives you a tab character.

---

Internally XNA handles the difference between path separator characters. You can use `\` or `/` (or some crazy combination of both) and it won't matter.

(I'm pretty sure Windows itself doesn't care which character you use either.)